# How is a scene graph a set of tree data structures?

Tags: javafx

I am getting started understanding the elements of JavaFX, and there are statements in the [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class that I do not get.

> A scene graph is a set of tree data structures where every item has zero or one parent, and each item is either a "leaf" with zero sub-items or a "branch" with zero or more sub-items.

Also...

> There may be several trees in the scene graph. Some trees may be part of a Scene, in which case they are eligible to be displayed. Other trees might not be part of any Scene.

What would be an example of a scene graph containing a set of trees?  A tree of nodes I can see.  Or of a scene graph containing a tree that is not in any scene?  TIA.

Comment: [`clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty--) / [`SubScene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html)